# ManyToMany associations between several "content type" entities and one "media" entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Symfony 2.5+ and Doctrine 2.2+, is it a bad idea to create multiple entities which all have a ManyToMany association with one other single shared entity?

### Background

Put on your thinking caps :) I am building 2.0 of our [existing CMS](http://www.gutensite.com) in Symfony 2.5 where we have many different "Content Types", e.g. Article, Profile, Map, Image, Video, Document, etc. When users create a new piece of content (based on one of these content types) they may choose images to associate with that content (yes the image is a content type as well).

The content types are really a CMS construct for making it easier for people to add content to the site. Each content type has a `controller` which determines what entity the content type maps to. For the most part, each content type has it's own `entity` for persisting the data. The image, document and video content types are a little different in that they all map to a shared `media` entity (so that I can easily manage the cloud storage for all these files from one table, since they are all essentially "media" and the content type distinction is largely just UI).

So my plan is to make a bidirectional `ManyToMany` association between each content type entity (e.g. `Articles`) and the `Media` entity. So that when someone selects an image to associate with an article, the association is mapped in a join table `article_media`. This will allow us to find all content where an image is in use, so that we don't delete an active image (or at least make sure they explicitly agree).

For the sake of simplification, we'll just map one `$media` association, instead of separate ones for images, documents and videos, which could also be associated with an article (I think we will handle this with a controller that extracts the full Media list for separate form inputs and then merges them back into the Media array for persistence, so that we don't have to make multiple calls to the database).

This requires that the `Article` entity have an association like this:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Gutensite\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", inversedBy="version", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="article_media")
 */
protected $media;
```

And the `Media` Entity will have an inverse association like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Gutensite\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article", mappedBy=“media”)
 */
protected $article;
```

But if I have multiple content types, each entity will need this as well, and so soon the `Media` entity will have a lot of additional associations:

```
// Article Association plus additional ones for each entity...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Gutensite\ProfileBundle\Entity\Profile", mappedBy=“media”)
 */
protected $profile;

/**
 * This is self referential since a video may need to specify a thumbnail image...
 * I'm not sure yet how best to do this, but it will be necessary.
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Gutensite\MediaBundle\Entity\Media", mappedBy=“media”)
 */
protected $media;

// ...etc...
```

This would end up creating unique join tables for **every** content type, e.g. `article_media`, `profile_media`, `media_media`. That is probably nice for keeping these tables smaller.

### Cons

The downside of this is that everytime we create a new content type, we have to add an additional association on the Media entity. If we start to get 10+ content types, that's a lot of associations. Is that a problem?

Any other problems?

### Alternatives

Is it possible to make the join table have a `entity` field that indicates the content type, so that we only have one join table for all the different content types? For example:

```
id | entity | entityId | MediaId
```

If so how would you define in Doctrine this extra `entity` distinction field to prevent collisions with `entityId` for different content types?

### Other Considerations

Later when we allow third party developers to create their own content types, this solution will no longer work because we don't want there to be hundreds of associations. So in this case, we thought that we would create an intermediate entity like `MediaMap`. Each entity will have a OneToMany relationship with `MediaMap` (uni-directional so that we only have to define the inverese side on `MediaMap` back to every content type). And then `MediaMap` will have a ManyToMany relationship with `Media` with a join table in between. That way `Media` will only maintain one association to the `MediaMap`.

This seems a bit cumbersome, and introduces another database query into the sequence, which I don't at all like.

### Solutions

So is there a better way to do this?

Should we just maintain our own `MediaMap` table manually, and not rely on Doctrine entity association?

Answer (score 1):

I think your first alternative is the best answer. You will have to do a manual lookup to get the original entity from the media, or to get all the media used by an entity, but you can write that as a utility class pretty quickly. This method will work no matter how many different content types you add in the future.

Your table would look like this

```
id  |  entity class (ie Biz/CMS/Article)  | entityId  | mediaId
```

There are ways to make this even more abstract that I am using on a project right now, but this would be a good start for your project.

Just out of curiosity, why did you choose to create your own CMS instead of using one of the existing options?

Comment: Ours (www.gutensite.com) is one of the existing ones :) but we are recreating it on a modern framework. We have some innovative ideas for content management that we are excited to implement, as well as a wanting to have complete control over the UI/UX. Nothing out there does what we want, without stripping it down. It's a hard decision to start from scratch. But we think it's the right one. And thankfully Symfony helps quite a bit.

Comment: You say the alternative idea is the best, but you are saying there is no way to implement that in Symfony/Doctrine? And I would just need to make an entity for this table and then have my utility class manually do the management (adding new records and fetching existing map)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you think this is the best method? And what is specifically bad about the multiple ManyToMany?

Comment: Yes, your utility class would manage the relationship. It isn't that the multiple ManyToMany is bad, but that it isn't reusable and extensible. By making that concrete link you have to maintain all of those relationships and tables for something that is used commonly across all of your objects. There is a term for this, it is called Aspect Oriented Development and it is a good design pattern for the problem you are trying to solve. You want to make this common "thing" easily usable, regardless of the object that is using the "thing".

Comment: Would you define this intermediary `MediaManager` table as a doctrine Entity? I assume you must, in order to do queries on it. Would you create uni-directional `OneToMany` relationships between each entity and this `MediaManager` so that they could be fetched easily by the entity? And/or would you create a `ManyToMany` relationship between the `MediaManager` and the `Media` entity, so that all the `mediaId` were related back to the `Media` entity?

Comment: Answer: Probably no on the `ManyToMany` association between `MediaManager` and `Media` since that would create another join table which gets us back into non ideal 4 table territory.

Comment: Answer: and probably no on the `OneToMany` from the entity to the `MediaManager` since the association would have to be defined on the `MediaManager` between each entity, which defeats the entire purpose again. So really we are going to bypass doctrine's entity associations completely.

Comment: You are correct. I would bypass the relationships entirely and let the MediaManager give you the media for an entity. MediaManager::getMedia(ArticleInterface $article). The ArticleInterface will need a getType() method, getId() method (although getId() is probably already part of your entity) and an addMedia method(). Any new article type will implement ArticleInterface and MediaManager will know how to get the media for that article. Of course, you will need a MediaManager::addMedia(ArticleInterface $article) as well.

Comment: If 100% of the time I'm going to need to take these `mediaId` values and do a subsequent lookup on the `Media` entity to get the real media value (e.g. the title and URL to the media). Then wouldn't it be better to make a ManyToMany association for that? So that it's handled with a join, rather than a separate query to find all `Media` IN the id list? The convenience is nice, for sure, but will that help or hinder performance?